# DismissView and push (or performSegueWithIdentifier) after Receive Remote Notification on appDelegate by swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple-push-notifications

How can i pushViewController after the modal which was presented ViewController on appDelegate file did dismissViewControllerAnimated function after receive remote notification?

I tried feedVc.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc1, animated: true) but nothing happended.

This is some code from my files.

//
AppDelegate.swift

```
self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabberController") as! DefaultTabbarController // this is FeedsViewController

let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("beatingDealView") as! UINavigationController

let bealBiddingVc: BeatBiddingModalViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! BeatBiddingModalViewController

bealBiddingVc.dealId = tempDealId
bealBiddingVc.beatBiddingText = tempDealText
bealBiddingVc.dealName = tempDealName

self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

// BeatBiddingModalViewController.swift

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {

        let vc1: DealInsideViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pushDealInsideFirstView") as! DealInsideViewController
        let feedVc:FeedsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("feedsDisplayView") as! FeedsViewController

        feedVc.feedsTableClickCheck = false
        feedVc.dealIdFromNoti = self.dealId
        feedVc.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc1, animated: true)
    })
```

Comment: How come DefaultTabbarController = FeedsViewController that does not make any sense. Should it be "self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabberController") as! FeedsViewController"

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing the DealInsideViewController that you are creating in FeedsViewController will be disposed with the modal view. The best way in my view if for you to create DealInsideViewController and call the FeedsViewController from it in viewDidLoad so when you dismiss FeedsViewController you will be back in DealInsideViewController not in the appDelegate

Try This:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabberController") as! FeedsViewController

let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("beatingDealView") as! UINavigationController

let bealBiddingVc: BeatBiddingModalViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! BeatBiddingModalViewController

bealBiddingVc.dealId = tempDealId
bealBiddingVc.beatBiddingText = tempDealText
bealBiddingVc.dealName = tempDealName

self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

To dismiss the popover just call `dismissPopoverAnimated` and that will take you back to FeedsViewController

Comment: self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabberController") as! DefaultTabbarController 

This make my app to be already on FeedsViewController. Then when i dismiss i was on FeedsViewController but it was not push to DealInsideViewController.And i also can't call it on viewdidload because FeedsViewController is also use on the other way not only for this purpose.

Comment: You cannot do that, you need to organize your views as a deck of cards, if you put one on top and dismiss you get the one behind. If you put one on top, than a second on top of the first and dismiss the first the second is going to go away as well and this is what is happening with your app.

Comment: I think your solution will make tabbar disappear?